# Speed up magento 1.9 checkout submit

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, email-templates

My checkout submit process is 7-8 sec slow. I am checking with profiler and found that this one takes more than 500ms.
Is it normal? I did not edit much the email order template.

```
layout/db_update: sales_email_order_items
frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items.phtml
frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml
locale/currency
frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml
```

Comment: you can check any events triggering when order submit

Comment: What do you mean events triggering? I am already checking with Aoe Profiler

Comment: @means checking custom module any observer call here and check observer code